# How to instantiate a Service with parameters in MVVM Light ViewModelLocator?

Tags: c#, mvvm, mvvm-light

I have been searching for about 3 hours.
I need to know how do I instantiate a Service with parameters that are produced by another service in MVVM Light's ViewModelLocator.

In my ViewModelLocator class I register my View Models and then register services that they use, like this:

```
        SimpleIoc.Default.Register<INetworkClient>(() => new NetworkClient());
        SimpleIoc.Default.Register<IApiClientAuthentication>(() => new ApiClientAuthentication());
        SimpleIoc.Default.Register<IApiClient>(() =>
        {
            INetworkClient networkClient = ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<INetworkClient>();
            return new ApiClient(networkClient, new Uri("https://someuri.com/"),
                                            authResponse.AdminUserId, authResponse.ApiKey);
        });
```

The problem is that the "authResponse" that I pass to the ApiClient above is a result produced by calling a method on implementation of IApiClientAuthentication (which I also register with IoC container above). That response is not available when I create the ApiClient above. How should I go about it.

Please, at least push me in the right direction.

Comment: It's not clear to me with the code you've posted where `authResponse` comes from or gets initialized.

Comment: @gleng authResponse comes from ApiClientAuthentication instance (namely its the result of calling authenicate() on it). The problem is it is not available at the moment of registration with IoC container.